# Django custom queryset returns nothing

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I am trying to write a **year level** filter for my **student profile list**, however, the query returns an empty [].

This is my Attendance model, manager and custom queryset:

```py
    class AttendanceQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
        def get_yearlevel(self, yearlevel):
            return self.filter(BCEID__YearLevel = yearlevel)

    class AttendanceManager(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return AttendanceQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
    
        def get_yearlevel(self, yearlevel):
            return self.get_queryset().get_yearlevel(yearlevel)
    
    class Attendance(models.Model):
        BCEID = models.OneToOneField(StudentProfile,primary_key=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        AttendanceRate = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        objects = AttendanceManager()
    
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.BCEID
```

StudentProfile model:

```py
    class StudentProfile(models.Model):
       RelatedPersonName = models.CharField(max_length=10)
       RelatedPersonFirstName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
       RelatedPersonFamName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
       StudentLegalName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
       StudentFamName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
       Email = models.CharField(max_length=130)
       Street1  = models.TextField(max_length=30)
       Suburb = models.CharField(max_length=30)
       State = models.CharField(max_length=5)
       PostCode = models.CharField(max_length=6)
       StudentLegalName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
       StudentFamName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
       StudentNo = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=10)
       Class = models.CharField(max_length=6)
       YearLevel = models.CharField(max_length=10)
       objects = StudentProfileManager()
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.StudentNo
```

and AttendanceListView (views.py)

```py
    class AttendanceListView(ListView):
       model = Attendance

       queryset = Attendance.objects.get_yearlevel("Year 8")
```

I manually queried the database to check if there were errors in my code, and got the same result: an empty array [].

SQL:

```sql
    SELECT "student_attendance"."BCEID_id",
       "student_attendance"."AttendanceRate"
    FROM "student_attendance"
    INNER JOIN "student_studentprofile"
       ON ("student_attendance"."BCEID_id" = "student_studentprofile"."StudentNo")
    WHERE "student_studentprofile"."YearLevel" = 'Year 8'
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Do you have entry in DB? did you check if there is any uppercase/lowercase issue with string?

Comment: Hi Ruddra, I have entries in my DB and they are the same format as the argument (‘Year 8’). Although, I did try different combinations as well.

Comment: Do your tables have same name as it queries? Each table must match DBName_TableName pattern